# Save Login Data in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to save Login form data and after click on login it switch to logout page. and when we click logout it come back to login form.

Comment: can you show some code what you trying to do? and if you want to save the data after login then you can use NSUserDefault

Comment: This question shows zero effort on solving

Comment: I'm saving data from registration form when i click register button it shows message that data is saved and switch to login form now i want same credentials that when we enter email and password and click login button it show message login success and switch to logout page. @BhupatBheda

Comment: After getting the response from server then you save the data or only you locally save the data and please show some code what you trying to do in your code

Comment: what u tried..?  what is ur issue u r facing...?... give some ur code to understand ur issue... @Hamza

Comment: NSString *firstName = [_name text];
 NSString *email  = [_emailID text];
 NSString *phone  = [_phoneNo text];
 NSString *password  = [_password text];
 NSString *confirmPass  = [_reenterPassword text];
 NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
    [defaults setObject:phone forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [defaults setObject:email forKey:@"email"];
    [defaults setObject:password forKey:@"password"];
    [defaults setObject:confirmPass forKey:@"confirmPass"];
    [defaults synchronize];NSLog(@"Succuess");

Comment: above code is for new user registration and when click register button it switches to login form.now i want to login the user with same data provided in registration form to login. after login it should switch to logout page. @NAVEENKUMAR

Comment: So what's issue you are facing then

Comment: actually  i want when user click login then it display home screen and in left menu bar where there is an option of login it should change to logout and when we click that logout it display login form again. @BhupatBheda

Comment: Im giving the wrong email and clicking the login button it is taking me to logout. I want a check than the login email should be same as they had entered in registration form.

Comment: [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"UserLogin"]; when you save the other data in register and after that when you open left menu bar check @"UserLogin" bool value if its true display logout and when your press on logout set it to false and redirect it to login form

Comment: check it @Hamza my answer

Comment: i don't get it can u elaborate it? @ NAVEEN KUMAR

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**updated code:**

**for login Action :**

```
   -(IBAction)loginAction:(id)sender{

            NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            //username. ur viewcontroller usernamefild means email
            //password1 ur password field means password
            if ([username isEqualToString:[defaults valueForKey:@"email"]] && [password1 isEqualToString:[defaults valueForKey:@"confirmPass"]]) {
                NSLog(@"register successfull");
           [defaults setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"success"];
           [defaults synchronize];
            }else{
                NSLog(@"error");

            }
        }
```

**when u click in register/login cell action check the condition like**

```
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"success"] isEqualToString:@"YES"]) {
            // push the logout VC using segway
        }else{
            //push login page VC
        }
```

Comment: its giving error for confirm password

Comment: what error ...?

Comment: No visible @interface for 'UITextField' declares the selector 'isEqualtoString:'. This is the error

Comment: username :  ur emailtextfield-reference and password1 is ur passwordreference.  u need to set like username.text and password1.text

Comment: check now my updated comment

Comment: Let me explain. Actually in the left menu bar where there is login/register when i click it it shows login form. The left menu bar is not made by me i have made that by just putting some classes from the ready made project. There working is just when we click them it opens login form. Login form opens through the segue identifier . Now i want when i click the login form with the correct data. The text in left menu bar where there is login it should change to logout and when we click that logout it open again empty fields login form. and logout text change to login as before.@NAVEEN KUMAR

Comment: check now   @Hamza

Comment: u checked code..?

Comment: Cells are static in left menu bar and i have took the code from a project build by another person from GitHub. Now I'm confuse were should i place ur logout code because left menu bar is using the built classes and i don't know about the internal working of that code. @NAVEEN KUMAR

Comment: have u understand the real issue? @NAVEEN KUMAR